# Deriving the equations of motion. Finding the critical points and determining their nature.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have [Duffing equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) as

$\ddot{x} - x + x^3 = 0$

Which I know describes the motion of a mechanical system in a twin well potential.

I have let $y_1 = x, y_2 = \dot{x}$ and I want to derive the equations of motion for

$y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$

And thus find the critical points of the system and the nature of them.

$y' = \begin{pmatrix} y_1'\\y_2' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_2 \\ x'' \end{pmatrix}$

So I think I need $y_2 = 0$ and $x''=0$.

Critical points at $-x+x^3 = 0$ goes to $x(-1+x^2)=0$ so $x=0$ or $x=\pm1$.

Now I need to go do eigenvalues of something, but I have no coefficients matrix normally $A$??

Comment: Take a deep breath, you are young, take your time.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval i calmed it down, can you help?

Comment: Thank you @Anomaly I didn't know how to do that doubler dot

Comment: No problem at all. If you're interested, the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List" is great for finding commands for some of the more uncommon notation.

Comment: Trying to do a bounty this way doesn't work. Please read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves your equation:

%This part in a .m file:

function xd=duffing_f(t,y)

xd=zeros(2,1);

xd(1)=y(2);
xd(2)=y(1)-y(1)^3;

% And this in another one .m file

[t,y]=ode45('duffing_f',[0 20],[0 1]);

%

Using this code you can obtain the following representation of your problem.

[image]

I hope that using it you can understand better whats is happening.

Comment: This is definitely nice! I will keep at it with this helping me!